# Implementing bidirectional relations between objects of the same class

Tags: java, class-design

I have to implement a class whose instances have a bidirectional relation to each other. For example I have the class `FooBar` which should offer the method `sameAs(FooBar x)` and maintain a Set for each instances containing its equivalent instances. So if I call `foo.sameAs(bar)`, the Set in `foo` should contain `bar` and vice versa. Invoking `bar.sameAs(foo)` doesn't work, of course.

For clarifiction: the instances of this class are only **semantically** equal. `equals` should still return `false`.

The solutions I've come up with is either to implement a private method `internalSameAs(FooBar x)` which is invoked from `sameAs(FooBar x)` or to use a static method `sameAs(FooBar x, FooBar y)`.

Solution 1:

```
class FooBar {
    Set<FooBar> sameAs = new HashSet<FooBar>();

    public void sameAs(FooBar x) {
        this.internalSameAs(x);
            x.internalSameAs(this);
        }

        public void internalSameAs(FooBar x) {
            sameAs.add(x);
        }
    }
```

Solution 2:

```
class FooBar {
    Set<FooBar> sameAs = new HashSet<FooBar>();

    public static void sameAs(FooBar x, FooBar y) {
        x.sameAs.add(y);
        y.sameAs.add(x);
    }
}
```

Which one would you prefer and why? Or is there another way I didn't think about?

Comment: It's hard to get the question. Maybe some pseudo code can make your point more clear.

Comment: Should the `Set` of equivalent objects **always** be complete and correct or is it sufficient to "cache" `sameAs` calls that returned `true`?

Comment: @Joachim It should always be complete and correct

Comment: Are `FooBar` objects mutable? In that case it might get very hairy! If they are immutable, it could become very easy.

Comment: Also, since it might be important: **Why** do you need the set of all equivalent instances? What about garbage-collection? Why have equivalent instances in the first place and not just use the same object?

Comment: @Joachim To account for garbage collection it is of course my responsibility to make sure that no unused instances is still present in any set.

Comment: @joe776: so, if "sameness" can't be determined programatically, how do you plan to populate your sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you flexible with the data structures to be used? If so you could use a `Multimap` (from [Guava Collections](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)) that is static amongst all the instances of the class `FooBar`. In that `Multimap` you can have the keys as `FooBar` references (or a unique id if you have one) and the values would be the references (or id.s) of the `FooBar`s that have the `sameAs` relation.

Comment: Having a global map for `sameAs` instances won't work in my case.

Comment: @joe776: and **why** exactly is that? If you give more details about your problem, we might be able to help better.

Comment: I agree with Joachim, if you can elaborate I/we can refine/reformulate suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The naming you've used is confusing. `sameAs` sounds as though it's a test which should return a boolean, but from your code it seems it would be more appropriately named `declareSameAs`. When you call `foo.sameAs(bar)`, you're declaring that `foo` and `bar` are the same, not doing a test, correct?

The problem is that with your code you can declare

```
x.sameAs(y);
y.sameAs(z);
```

but it won't be the case that x is the same as z, which is presumably not what you want (and if it is what you want, you definitely need to change the method name).

It seems to me you want to divide your instances into sets, and have each instance keep a reference to the set it's in (*not* to a separate set internal to the instance).  When you make a new declaration that two instances are the same, you need to combine the sets, and ensure all affected instances have a reference to the combined set.

Comment: +1 for spotting the bad naming. I read the method name and automatically assumed it was a comparison method that returned a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Your "bidirectional" `samesAs(...)` method sounds like `Object.equals(...)`, which, according to [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is a "an equivalence relation on non-null object references". If this is what you want, then you just have to override `equals` in your class.

I'm a bit lost when you say that "`FooBar` shouldmaintain a Set for each instances containing its equivalent instances". If you want to build equivalent classes for `FooBar` objects, then I think it's a good idea to use a java `Collection` to represent them, and more precisely a `Set`.

Here is a quickly hacked example:

```
public class FooBar {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        // do whatever fancy computation to determine if 
        // the object other is equal to this object
    }

}
```

and for the equivalent class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FooBarEquivalentClass extends HashSet<FooBar> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(FooBar e) {
        if (isEmpty())
            return super.add(e);
        else if (e.equals(iterator().next()))
            return super.add(e);
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with using a Set? Like in the added example code above?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a different way: `sameAs` sounds pretty similiar to `equals`. If we do not need `equals` for something else, then I'd simply implement the `equals` method on `FooBar` so that we simply do a

```
 if (foo.equals(bar))
    System.out.println("We're equal (aka: 'equivalent/the same')");
```

In this case, we do not need any set - just a rule to determine, if two instances *are equal*.

---

You could store the *sameness* information in a separate datastructure outside of those classes. A central map could do the job:

```
 HashMap<FooBar, Set<FooBar>> sameFooBars;
```

If you have "same" objects, simply add them to the map:

```
 public static void addSameObjects(FooBar foo1, FooBar foo2) {
   Set<FooBar> set = getMap().get(foo1);
   if (set == null) {
     set = new HashSet<FooBar>();
     getMap().put(foo1, set);
   }
   set.add(foo2);

   // serious implementation avoid code duplication...
   set = getMap().get(foo2);
   if (set == null) {
     set = new HashSet<FooBar>();
     getMap().put(foo2, set);
   }
   set.add(foo1);
}
```

And the test:

```
public static boolean isSame(FooBar foo1, FooBar foo2) {
  if (getMap().get(foo1) == null) 
    return false;

  return getMap().get(foo1).contains(foo2);
}
```

Comment: Implementing `equals` unfortunately won't work as they are only semantically the same, which can not be determined programmatically.

Comment: @joe776 - so how do you calculate "sameness" - or is it a user decision?

Comment: Yes, it's entirely decided by the user.

Comment: @joe776 - that supports the idea of a separate datastructure for that sort of metadata (see my last edit)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to maintain a list of equivalences in ALL objects? If possible I would separate the set of equivalences from the objects themselves. This will be easier to maintain.

Then you can use the multimap of @posdef or more simply a Map> to stay with standard JAVA API.

Comment: The benefit of using a `Multimap` is that the class itself uses a collection to store "values". So all you need to do is `map.put(k,v)` which then automatically becomes `map.getValues(k).add(v)` (pseudocode). Using standard library for the same purpose is possible (something like Map<Key, Collection<Value>>) but would require manual labor to maintain the collection of values.

Comment: Personnaly I don't like to add a new dependancy just to eliminate a few lines out of the total codebase. In particular, in case of collection API, I prefer to stick with the standard if I have no big reason to do otherwise. Staying standard is good. This mean that everybody know how this API works, that I'am sure the API will stay current in the years to come and that I avoid the need for code that convert from one API to another. If everybody where using custom collections API this would only increase the line of code for doing the proper conversion between all theses API.

Answer (score 0):

"same as" but not "equal to" sounds like you should be using [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

I think it makes more sense to implement [`compareTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) or `sameAs()` as an instance method rather than a static since you will always need two real instances to do any comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want are to separate the equivalence groups from the object instances.

Make a Map<FooBar, Set<FooBar>> and note that when you lookup an object the set will include itself.